# How to measure incoming message size for asmx web services

Tags: c#, web-services

is there any way to measure to measure the incoming message size for asmx web services, i have a method like this

```
int SaveData(int storeID, Products[] product)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does any one have any suggestions on this